# ARM - Is calling function from external static library possible?

Tags: ida, arm, android

Basically i'm debugging a closed source binary on Android and i want to execute some of my code in between which is large enough not to fit in codecave. So is it possible to compile library with my code separately & then calling it from target binary?
If yes then how?

My friend suggested me to modify binary header & extend data segment to inject my code. Is it convenient?

I have another one suggestion.
I know interface to that closed source binary, then is it possible to write a wrapper binary?
For ex, suppose closed source binary is libfoo.so. Then is it possible to write a binary libbar.so which actually loads libfoo.so & sends function calls to libfoo.so

I'm asking this because i've seen some warez programs bundled with some extra dlls & often some wrapper executable.

Answer (score 4):

"Wrapping" is definitely possible, one of the techniques I normally use for Android reverse engineering is "shimming" the binary. Essentially you write a small application, either Java/Application based or C/Native based. An example of doing this is here;

https://github.com/rednaga/native-shim

This allows you to call any method you would like with slight modifications.

Answer (score 2):

If this library is linked statically, you can not change it without changing the executable. However you can use [Frida](http://frida.re) during debugging session to intercept specific calls, automate this task and run your own code written in (surprise!) JavaScript.

See [simple example here](http://www.frida.re/docs/quickstart/) for more details.